# how to find all nested documnet in mongodb by key

Tags: python, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm newbie in Mongo. For every record that is saved, the names of keys *packageNAme* and environment and field_variable are changeable, and the rest are unchanged. I want to return **all** environments of them according to the user's needs.
How can I query on nested document keys?

```json
{
    "header": {
        "packagename": {
            "environmentNum1": {
                "field_variable1": {
                    "firstName": "my_first_name",
                    "lastName": "my_last_name",
                    "age": 20
                }
            },
            "environmentNum2": {
                "field_variable2": {
                    "firstName": "yourt_name",
                    "lastName": "your_last_name",
                    "age": 28
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using dynamic field name is generally considered as anti-pattern and you should avoid that. Nevertheless, you may opt for [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) for manipulating the field and converted k-v tuples for your case.

Comment: try to not save data in the names of the fields, save the schema(metadata) only, so its known and easier to query it. If you keep this schema, if you can add the expected result.